# Phonegap + Barcode scanner plugin code example

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is there some good example for phonegap + Barcode scanner [plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/261) code example??? I could not find any in Internet!

([Demo](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeDemo) apparently is not fully packaged app)

Comment: What do you mean by "_fully packaged app_"? I have just successfully built (through PhoneGap Build) both [demo](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeDemo) and my own application basing on it. I see no problems. Provide more details, please.