# ManateeWords plugin phonegap project works in Chrome but white screen on phonegap developer app

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap

Hi folks I have created a phonegap project and installed 'ManateeWords plugin' and configured by following github instructions and email support from Manatee.  It displays proper splash screen in Chrome but Phonegap Developer app on my ios phone shows white screen and hangs(have to uninstall/install to get it to work.

Did some research and downloaded a different barcode scanner (
[Phonegap + Barcode scanner plugin code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032585/phonegap-barcode-scanner-plugin-code-example)) and similar but not identical behaviour.  Shows perfectly in Chrome on my Mac desktop but instead of white screen on PhoneGap developer app it says 'DOWNLOAD ERROR' Alert Unable to download archive from the server please enter valid url to connect to'.  I double checked url for path to my project and it is correct.

Any thoughts on what might be going on with phonegap developer app for either of these plugins?

Thanks in advance, Cat

Comment: Correction: I got the second plugin from here 'https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner' to work.  So it is just the plugin from Manatee that is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap Developer App is a tool to preview your app, but it has some limitations.
Phonegap Developer App is really a Phonegap app itself, and it can only use the plugins that were included when it was built. That's the Cordova core plugins and a few 3rd party plugins.

You can see all the plugins included on the [app's github repo](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/blob/bb9452c2c1562a1b27e04f69be9fa30192d1ae47/config.xml#L66-L109)

You'll see that the ManateeWords plugin is not there, so you can't use it on the Phonegap Developer App.

Comment: That link points to an out of date in an older version of the config.xml file for PhoneGap. The latest version does contain this plug-in " <plugin name="manateeworks-barcodescanner-v3" spec="^3.0.43" />"

Comment: @catpedersen, no, that's a permalink to current plugins, you can check it on the repo if you want, that plugin is not there

Comment: @jcesarmoble you were 100% correct.  Phonegap itself supports the Manatee plugin but it will not run on Phone Gap Developer's App.  Company say's it is Adobe's choice not theirs.